# Edit my profile on iOS

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

I've looked everywhere but can't seem to find a way to edit my profile from the iOS app - is this even possible?

Answer (score 2):

No. It is not possible. Only the really important stuff is there: asking questions, answering questions, editing, etc.

I don't think it is really necessary to be able to edit your profile from the app. How often do you do that anyway? I would rather see other things implemented that could be useful a lot more.

Comment: Well I'm in hospital with time to kill and no laptop, so I thought I'd update my profile. Oh well.

Comment: Ah. That is awesome. No better moment that to check out the latest on your favorite site. Get well soon! @dave